# Excel copy downwards

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

In MS Excel, if you select two cells containing text like "x1", "x2" and drag the bottom-right corner of the selection, it continues the pattern "x3", "x4", "x5" etc.

Is there a way to do this using the keyboard?

Ctrl-D fills downwards, but only by duplicating the first cell.

Comment: I agree with CharlieRB, this appears to be a duplicate question.  Can you add more detail about how your question is different?

Comment: Yep, 270018 answers this quite nicely.  So the keyboard shortcut (in Excel 2002) is: Alt, E, I, S, Alt-F, Enter

Answer (score 0):

Drag the bottom-right corner while holding the Ctrl key. It will alternate x1 and x2. At least it does in Excel 2007 and 2010.

If you wish to do this without using the mouse at all:

- select the cells x1 and x2 (use shift, and arrow or home/end buttons)
- press Ctrl-C
- select the cells you wish to fill
- press Ctrl-V

X1 and x2 are alternating, at least in Excel 2010.

Comment: -1, this appears to repeat what the OP has already tried, that is dragging with the mouse.  The question is whether it can be done with the keyboard. Perhaps you could clarify your answer a bit.

Comment: I assumed he was ok using the mouse, just failed to get the desired result.